# Use BeautifulSoup to extract string from script tag

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to build a scraper that will print out the name of the current daily leetcode question, in python using BeautifulSoup

```
import requests
import datetime
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

LEETCODE_URL = "https://leetcode.com/problemset/all"

def main():
    response = requests.get(LEETCODE_URL)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
    
    current_date = datetime.datetime.now()
    formatted_date = current_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    
    daily_question = soup.find_all(string=formatted_date)
    print(daily_question)
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Printing out soup, I notice that there's the text `"2023-07-14"` and a little bit after that, the name of the question. So I just have to get the index of that and search from that index for the `title` string.

But using the code I provided above, it prints out an empty list... Even though the string should be present in `soup`, and I do not understand why.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you might have known leetcode uses script with json to load data. You can just grab that json to python and use it.

```
import requests
import datetime
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

LEETCODE_URL = "https://leetcode.com/problemset/all"

def main():
    response = requests.get(LEETCODE_URL)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
    
    current_date = datetime.datetime.now()
    formatted_date = current_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    
    json_text = soup.find(id='__NEXT_DATA__').text
    json_data = json.loads(json_text)
    for challenge in json_data["props"]["pageProps"]["dehydratedState"]["queries"][2]["state"]["data"]["dailyCodingChallengeV2"]["challenges"]:
        print(challenge["date"])
        print(challenge["userStatus"])
        print(challenge["link"])
        print(challenge["question"]["title"])
        print('*'*50)
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Output:

```
2023-07-01
NotStart
/problems/fair-distribution-of-cookies/
Fair Distribution of Cookies
**************************************************
2023-07-02
NotStart
/problems/maximum-number-of-achievable-transfer-requests/
Maximum Number of Achievable Transfer Requests
**************************************************
2023-07-03
NotStart
/problems/buddy-strings/
Buddy Strings
**************************************************
2023-07-04
NotStart
/problems/single-number-ii/
Single Number II
**************************************************
2023-07-05
NotStart
/problems/longest-subarray-of-1s-after-deleting-one-element/
Longest Subarray of 1's After Deleting One Element
**************************************************
2023-07-06
NotStart
/problems/minimum-size-subarray-sum/
Minimum Size Subarray Sum
**************************************************
2023-07-07
NotStart
/problems/maximize-the-confusion-of-an-exam/
Maximize the Confusion of an Exam
**************************************************
2023-07-08
NotStart
/problems/put-marbles-in-bags/
Put Marbles in Bags
**************************************************
2023-07-09
NotStart
/problems/substring-with-largest-variance/
Substring With Largest Variance
**************************************************
2023-07-10
NotStart
/problems/minimum-depth-of-binary-tree/
Minimum Depth of Binary Tree
**************************************************
2023-07-11
NotStart
/problems/all-nodes-distance-k-in-binary-tree/
All Nodes Distance K in Binary Tree
**************************************************
2023-07-12
NotStart
/problems/find-eventual-safe-states/
Find Eventual Safe States
**************************************************
2023-07-13
NotStart
/problems/course-schedule/
Course Schedule
**************************************************
2023-07-14
NotStart
/problems/longest-arithmetic-subsequence-of-given-difference/
Longest Arithmetic Subsequence of Given Difference
**************************************************
```

You can copy/paste the json-response in console or https://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer to see json more clearly.

Comment: That works great. But how did you find the exact path of the json?

Comment: it's not xpath per se. Just ID of element. I just opened dev-tools in browser and searched for "2023-07-14"and copied the ID of script.

Comment: @neogru if you are asking about the values in json data, I pasted json in codebeautify site then switched mode to View then traced the keys. There might be other ways.